# there is a way of import bulma at nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

recent im trying to use nuxt after a long time, i see that nuxt cannot allow install bulma in the making of project but im triying to import manually installing bulma with npm and calling this at nuxt.config

```js
 
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources'

  ],

  axios: {},

  build: {},

  styleResources:{
     scss: ['./assets/main.scss']
  }
```

but this send error screen:

[image]

im trying to find a solve for this problem but im not found solve...
some friend can help me to solve this?

thanks for the answers

My main.scss file:

```js
    
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "~bulma/bulma";
```

im try to change import at App.js to  '../node_modules/bulma/sass/bulma.sass'

but this does not work...

Comment: Did my answer helped somehow ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Load it from a CDN. It is better as there are chances that it will be already cached in the user's browser. Example *nuxt.config.js*:

```js
head: {
    title: [...],
    meta: [...],
    link: [
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        type:"text/css",
        href: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css'
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need Bulma exactly but you may install Buefy (Bulma for Vue) which is really complete in terms of components and integrates really easily. The nuxt install is super simple too.

It can also be configured with Bulma's styling config variables and have access to pretty much everything that you may need (as far as I know).

Here is the link for the Buefy's install with Nuxt: https://buefy.org/documentation/start#nuxtjs

PS: also, the maintainer is a cool guy and may help on Discord if you have any specific questions related to Buefy.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using `node-sass` and `sass-loader` simply:

1. Create a sass file under your `assets` folder. Ex: `assets/bulmaConfig.sass`.

   In this file you can apply all the customization options described in [the docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/#6-add-your-own-bulma-styles).
2. Add the file in your `nuxt_config.js` like:

   ```
   ...
   css: [
     '@/assets/scss/bulmaConfig.sass',
      ...
   ]
   ...
   ```

If you're not using `node-sass` and `sass-loader`:

```
npm i -D node-sass sass-loader
```

And follow the same steps above.